# How to receive intent from one activity to adapter class of another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, adapter

I am setting a intent from my **Activity A** for **activity B**.

And i want to receive my that intent in the adapter class (getView()) of Activity B.

```
Class A {
    Intent i new Intent(A.class,B.class)
    i.putExtra("abc",abc);
    startActivity(i)
}



Class B {
    myAdapter=MyAdapter(context,counter[])
    list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}



MyAdapeter extends BaseAdapter {
    getView(){

    }
}
```

i want value of abc in getview... How?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most straightforward way would be to create an instance variable in your adapter's class:

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public String myString;

    getView(){
        // use myString here
    }
}
```

And set it when creating the adapter in Activity B:

```
Class B {
    myAdapter = MyAdapter(context,counter[])
    myAdapter.myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("abc");
    list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```